# Flyout Theme Bug When Using Custom RequestedTheme On Any Element

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have the following situation in Windows Phone 8.1:

1. Emulator with Dark theme
2. A Page Flyout
3. An element with RequestedTheme="Light" (inside a DataTemplate, in many pages)

This happens:

1. Open a flyout: it is Dark (as the app theme). Ok.
2. Navigate to a page that there is the element with RequestedTheme="Light". Ok.
3. Open a flyout: it is Light! Not ok!

**Now all my Flyouts are Light. But my ApplicationTheme is still Dark. 
It seems to be a bug.**

Does anybody see if I am doing anything wrong?

--

Additional info: Flyouts doesn't have a RequestedTheme property, so I think it use the ApplicationTheme. But maybe there is something else.

Comment: By now I'm using the following workaround and it works: I'm loading my custom Dark resources AFTER the Light resources in my App.xaml:

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Resources/LightThemeResources.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Resources/DarkThemeResources.xaml"/>